# Is it possible to provision a replica set using MongoDB MMS?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I was wondering if it is possible to provision a replica set (or any other deployment schema) using the MongoDB MMS API. It is possible using the UI, but we want to automate that process from another internal system. I took a look at the API documentation but it wasn't clear to me if you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Public MMS API](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/api/) does not (as at December 2014) have support for Provisioning or Deployment yet. Full Automation API support is definitely on the product roadmap, though.

Current API methods provide access to user management, monitoring, alerts, and backup/restore functionality.

Comment: Note: the best source of information for release notes and product updates is the MMS Blog ["Release-Notes"](http://blog.mms.mongodb.com/tagged/Release-Notes) category.